# Using an Objective-C protocol from my XPC Service in my Swift app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, nsxpcconnection

I have an app that is written in Swift, exclusively in Swift, never had an Obj-C class, has no Obj-C files or bridging headers.

In order to add some functionality without impacting my app's entitlements, I'm trying to add an XPC service -- I created this in Xcode, and the template for XPC services in Xcode is Obj-C only.

This is fine, I wrote my service out in Obj-C, but now when I want to call my service through `NSXPCConnection` I've gotta set up the interface to it, and to do that I need to refer, in my Swift app code, to the Obj-C protocol I wrote for my XPC target.

How do I do this?  I can't just add the "Protocol.h" to my app target, it has no rule for a C header.  All the other commentary I've found on this only seems to apply to linking to a protocol in a framework or a common target...

Comment: I'm totally curious how you are going to manage to make this work, and can merely suggest this: add `Protocol.h` to your **Swift** app, add a `Bridging-Header` to that app (simplest way is to create then delete an Obj-C class and click *Create Bridging Header* when prompted), and `#import "Protocol.h"` in the bridging headers. You will then be able to pick a **Swift** class inheriting `NSObject`, and make it adopt the `Protocol`.

Comment: I've decided to just roll the functionality into the app for now, putting it in an XPC would have been nice but it's not obligatory.  I lack the Xcode-do necessary to build an XPC service in swift without a template, I'll wait until Apple puts one out.  I tried a couple different things and nothing works...

Comment: You know what, I just got it to build, lemmie make sure it works and I'll write it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out a solution.

1) Deleted the boilerplate Obj-C service class and protocol files.

2) Wrote my protocol and vended object classes in swift.  Made sure these could be exported to Obj-C.

3) Added the protocol.swift file to my app's target.  Added `#import "Service-Swift.h"` to my service's `main.m`.

So now my XPC object is implemented in Swift, my object protocol is in swift, the only non-swift file is my XPC's main.

Comment: You also could use `main.swift` to stay off from Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you can even change your main file. 
https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/xpc/